# Typescript not recognizing HTML property

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-scroll

I'm using TypeScript in my Vite React project. I'm having problems to build my project because of this error, says that the `name` property doesn't exist. Someone know how I can fix that?

```
Type '{ children: Element; name: string; className: string; }' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>'.
  Property 'name' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>'.
```

The code

```
<div
  name='contact'
  className='w-full h-screen bg-dark text-white flex justify-center items-center p-4'
>
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use `name` on a `div`?

Comment: It's to use a Link componet from react-scroll. It need the name as reference.

Comment: Then you should use `react-scroll`'s `Element` component instead

Answer (score 1):

The property `name` does not exists on a `HTMLDivElement`

Instead you can use the `Element` from `react-scroll`

```js
import { Element } from "react-scroll";

<Element name="contact" className="w-full">
  Scroll to this element
</Element>;
```

or if you want to scroll to your **own** element e.g. `div`, you can use a `id`

```js
<div
  id="contact"
  className="w-full h-screen bg-dark text-white flex justify-center items-center p-4"
></div>
```